# How to add suffix to numbers in CForm?

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, number-representation

I want to create C-Code from some expressions which have many explicit floating point numbers in them. I need real numbers to be in quadruple and not double precision.

Is there a way to add a 'q' suffix to all numbers when applying CForm, 
i. e. write 0.05q instead of 0.05?

I know, that I can use NumberForm to do this without CForm

```
NumberForm[#, 32, NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "q", #3}] &)] &
```

but it does not work anymore after applying CForm.

Comment: `ToString[CForm[0.05]]`<>"q" ?

Comment: This does not work for me, as I was searching for a way to add the "q" to every real number in the expression and not just to a single one. Doing it by hand is not feasible.

Comment: It is obvious you can use `Map`. Take example from Carl Woll answer: `ToString[CForm[#]] <> "q" & /@ {N[Pi], N[Pi^100, 50], N[Pi^-30, 25]}` gives the same answer. Or you can use replasement rule: `{N[Pi], N[Pi^100, 50], N[Pi^-30, 25]} /. x_Real :> ToString[CForm[x]] <> "q"`.

Comment: For arbitrary expression: `Sin[12.] + 5 Sqrt[1.3] /. x_Real :> ToString[CForm[x]] <> "q"` gives `5.164304207495255q`.

Answer (score 4):

I would override the default formatting of real numbers in [`CForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CForm). One possibility similar to yours is:

```
Unprotect[Real];
Format[r_Real, CForm] := Format[
    ToString @ NumberForm[
        r, 
        32, 
        NumberFormat->(Row[{#1, "e", #3,"q"}]&),
        NumberPadding->{"", ""}
    ],
    OutputForm
]
Protect[Real];
```

The [`OutputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OutputForm) formatting strips quotes from strings. Then:

```
{N[Pi], N[Pi^100, 50], N[Pi^-30, 25]} //CForm
```

> List(3.141592653589793q,5.1878483143196131920862615246303e49q,
>      1.217597700325186296592143e-15q)

With this approach there is no need to postprocess the output of [`CForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CForm).

Comment: I was exactly looking for something like this but could not find it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating C code from the Wolfram language, you will find the `SymbolicC` package useful.

```
Needs["SymbolicC`"]
CConstant[0.05, "q"] // ToCCodeString
```

> "0.05q"

To handle an expression using `SymbolicC`

```
expr = 2.4 a + 4.1 b;
ToCCodeString[CExpression[expr] /. r_Real :> aq[r]];
StringReplace[%, "aq(" ~~ Shortest[r__] ~~ ")" :> r <> "q"]
```

> "a*2.4q + b*4.1q"

Comment: +1 - SymbolicC is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

So after some searching and trying things, I found a solution.
I modified the solution given in https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1085655 where a somewhat similar but different problem was dealt with:

```
 mapReplace[exp_] := 
   MapAt[acf[ToString[NumberForm[#, 32, NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "e", #3, "q"}] &), 
      NumberPadding -> {"", ""}]]] &, exp, Position[exp, _Real]]

CNumberReformat[expr_] := 
 StringReplace[StringReplace[
   ToString[mapReplace[expr],CForm]
   , {Shortest["acf(\"" ~~ x__ ~~ "\")"] :> "(" <> x <> ")"}], {"eq" :> "q"}]
```

The first function replaces the numbers with a dummy function acf with the number as argument. The number is correctly formatted using NumberForm, i. e. the 'q' is added.
The second function then replaces this with the correct string.